# Android GCM MismatchSenderID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Im trying to implement Push Notification in my android app. I followed the **Google GCM's documentation**. I get the **SenderId** and **API Key** from the **Google API Console**. I generated **RegId** by using the SenderId. But when I Push the message from my server, It returns "**MismatchSenderId**".

I saw some samples but i couldn't understand the things. Can anyone help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: put here your menifest file.

Comment: I have to change anything in my manifest file.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't change the sender ID used by your app at some point?